# how does flink compute the "jobid" and store in jobarchive when the flink job finishes?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink, jobs are assigned job ids like `73ca9d2c10693ff8fd002738a7fc538a`. Any pointers on how this job id is computed?

Answer (score 0):

Flink job ids are randomly generated numbers.  See `JobID.java` and `AbstractID.java` for details.

```
    /**
     * Constructs a new random ID from a uniform distribution.
     */
    public AbstractID() {
        this.lowerPart = RND.nextLong();
        this.upperPart = RND.nextLong();
    }
```